# Listviews And Drag and Drop in C#

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to use drag and drop between two Listviews (AllListView and PreListView). This is how far I did get:

In the function where the AllListView is filled with Items, I use something like that to assosiate the myCustomDataObject to the single ListviewItem:

```
ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem();
newItem.Text = myCustomDataObject.getName();
newItem.Tag = myCustomDataObject;
lst_All.Items.Add(newItem);
```

There are my Eventhandler for the two Listviews:

AllListView:

```
private void OnAllDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    // How Do I add my CustomDataObject?
}

private void OnAllItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    base.DoDragDrop(lst_All.SelectedItems[0], DragDropEffects.Move);
    // Do I have to Do something to pass my CustomDataObject?
}
```

PreListView:

```
private void OnPreDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //If there one of myCustomDataObject go on
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void OnPreDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Get Here myCustomDataObject to generate the new Item
    lst_Pre.Items.Add("Done...");
}
```

So my question is, how to achieve that myCustomDataObject is found in “OnPreDragDrop”. I have tried many versions of e.Data.Getdata() and e.Data.Setdata(), but I did not got very far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dragging an object of type ListViewItem.  So you first want to check that the dragged item is indeed of that type.  And you probably want to make sure it is a happy kind of item, one that has the proper Tag value.  Thus:

```
private void OnPreDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListViewItem))) {
        var item = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));
        if (item.Tag is CustomDataObject) {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Drop event, you actually want to implement the logical "Move" operation, removing the item from the source ListView and adding it to the destination ListView.  No need for checks anymore, you already performed them in your DragEnter event handler.  Thus:

```
private void OnPreDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    var item = (ListViewItem)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListViewItem));
    item.ListView.Items.Remove(item);
    lst_Pre.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Note that you probably thought for a minute that the mistake was to drag the ListViewItem instead of the CustomDataObject.  It was not, dragging ListViewItem made it easy to remove the item from the source ListView.

Answer (score 0):

List view normally doesn't have drag and drop facility. But you can make it to do drag and drop with some changes with some extra code. Here is a link to help your problem. I hope you'll get something from it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822483

Comment: My Dear, this link suits people that have THIS symptons: "..you cannot **reorder** the items by dragging the items in the ListView control at run time. " The point is **reorder** and WITHIN a ListView... And sure do Listviews have Drag-And-Drop facility. Otherwise they would not did have Event-Handlers named like "OnDragDrop"... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `DoDragDrop`, you are assigning the data.  Make *that* your custom data object instead of the `ListViewItem`.

If you need the `ListViewItem`, then add a reference to it to your custom data class.

Comment: Actually I don't need the ListViewItem... So I Changed base.DoDragDrop(**lst_All.SelectedItems[0]**, DragDropEffects.Move); to base.DoDragDrop(**lst_All.SelectedItems[0].Tag**, DragDropEffects.Move);    But within OnPreDragEnter And OnPreDragDrop, the function "e.Data.GetData(typeof(myCustomData))" returns null and "e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(myCustomData))" returns false. Where is my mistake?